# Why font-awesome icons are not displayed in Mozilla firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, icons, font-awesome

I just downloaded a ready made template (design) for an e-commerce project but the font-awesome icons are not displaying while opening it with Mozilla firefox.

with the rest of browser it just works super fine like IE,Edge, Chrome and many others. I see squares instead of the icons in Mozilla firefox.

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|PT+Sans+Narrow|Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900&amp;subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900&amp;subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Here is the html for just an icon.

```
<li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>+1 456 6717</span></li>
```

Comment: Do you see any error in the ff console? Does it fail only on a published web site (on your hosting provider) or as well on your computer (localhost)?

Comment: it is local just a template on my local computer.

Comment: Share your html code of icons here

Comment: @pedram see updated question please.

Comment: According to the code above, you're just importing google fonts and not font-awesome, so I don't see how it could work on IE and Chrome

Comment: @EmilianoCostanzo what do you advise then? yeah it works with IE

Comment: @Dai Thanks a lot, but is it the right solution? solved my problem.

Comment: @NaserDostdar Glad it helped. Firefox has different "same origin" policy from other browsers, try to set up a simple local web server to get around the problem.